# Using linux epoll: epoll_ctl seems to have redundant parameter?

Tags: c++, linux, events, parameters, epoll

Usually on linux when we wish to use epoll, we first create a epfd, and then register fd and events to it.

```
 int fd=open(...)
 int epfd=epoll_create(1);
 epoll_event ev,events[1];
 ev.data.fd=fd;//already registered
 ev.events=EPOLLIN|EPOLLET;
 epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,fd,&ev);//still need to specify fd?
```

Above is a common example I found from internet. It works, but problem is:

> 1. ev.data.fd=fd here I already have my "fd" assigned to ev structure.
> 2. epoll_ctl still requires the 3rd parameter of this fd.

While the 4th parameter of epoll_ctl already contain information about this fd. This is why I think it's redundant.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ev.data` is a union. You *can* use the `fd` member, but you don't have to. You can also stick other data in there.

The point of `ev.data` is of course that *that*'s the data you get back when the event fires, so you need some way of relating that to the original file descriptor. Writing that very file descriptor into the `fd` variant is one simple way to achieve that, but other solutions exist.

One popular example is to define an abstract `class Fd`, derive concrete classes from it for particular purposes, and then write the upcast base pointer, converted to `void*`, into `ev.data.ptr`. On receipt of the event, you cast `ev.data.ptr` back to `Fd*` and invoke a suitable virtual member function to handle the event.

Answer (score 0):

"When fd is ready, return ev. You don't have to set ev.fd to fd."
I have no idea why the man page doesn't write this way, way easier to understand.